# angling the right border and left border using css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make a box slant its sides. I am trying to make right margin and left margin slant to their respective side. below is what I am trying to achieve

```
--------------------
\                  /
 ------------------
```

If you see in the above figure, the left side is at an angle instead of a straight line. Can this be achieved using CSS?

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Matthew Vines. The closest I've seen for this is CSS3 transform and skews. But will not achieve what you showed either.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the clever use of images, but not by straight css as far as I know.